# Updated Mongoose update nested array element

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

I have the following Schema

```
UserSchema: Schema = new Schema({
  username: String,
  password: String,
  chat: [{
    lastSeen: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    room: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'ChatRoom'
    }
  }],
});
```

I wanna make static method to the `UserSchema`, so that updates `chat[i].lastSeen` by given `room _id`

```
UserSchema.statics.lastSeen = 
function lastSeen(username: string, roomId: number, date: Date) {
   this.update({
    username: username,
    chat: {
        $elemMatch: {
            'room._id': roomId
        }
    }},
    {
        $set: { 'chat.$[???].lastSeen': date}
    });
}
```

I can't find out how to get the chat element by his element `room._id` and then update it. Any help?

**EDIT**

My case is similar but not the same as suggested duplicate, because the guy there knows all `ids`, where I don't know `chat._id`.

Comment: @JasonCust I read this and couldn't do it. Can you give a code for my specific case?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm posting the solution in case someone needs it.

```
UserSchema.statics.lastSeen = 
function lastSeen(username: string, roomId: number, date: Date) {
    this.update({
      username: username,
      'chat.room': roomId
    }, { $set: { 'chat.$.lastSeen': date }})
    .exec();
};
```

Comment: Also works from the Model (e.g. Model.update), no .exec is need in this case